# "Participate in" or "participate on"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which is the correct preposition in the sentence below? Why?

> Participated **in/on** producing quality software solutions for leading global insurance and reinsurance companies.

Comment: For stronger sentence, try "Produced quality software ...".

Comment: @RegDwight. Just for my own knowledge, I'd like to understand why this question was protected when all the dictionaries I checked showed that *to participate* is followed by the preposition *in*. I would have expected the question to be closed as general reference. What is it that makes it special?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Participate* is always followed by *in* and not *on* when referring to an activity.

Comment: *Participate in* sounds better with a noun following it than a gerund or verb.